# Standards that meets to ask some question on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, close-reasons

If someone asked question about something that he doesn't know. Like..

I am windows phone developer and my whole expertise are in windows phone and .NET technologies. And I want to do something like pothole detection with accelerometer. And I found nothing regarding .NET and Windows phone on internet and mostly topic are found are bases on Android and some examples also on Android. And as I mentioned I am not good in Android as I have never worked on that.

And as per my previous experience, I found stackoverflow very helpful site in this regard. And I ask question over there and people answer and help each other. So in my above scenario, I asked the question on stackoverflow describing my above problem statement and I also referred some links and my R&D as well. So I can get help from some one who is more proficient than me in Android and Windows Phone.

So what you say, I cannot ask such questions on stackoverflow and cannot seek help from other users on stackoverflow. Should my question will be closed as I didn't put some code (As mentioned above I found nothing regarding Windows Phone) because I don't have some starting point. I cannot seek any help and starting direction on that point in my above scenario.

Please needed your valuable comments on that topic. Is my above question doesn't justify to ask question on StackOverflow?

Comment: [The question (presumably) in question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886174/pothole-detetction-with-accelrometer-in-windows-phone)

Comment: You put more effort into *this* question than you did *that* question. Put more effort into *that* one and it would be useful. As it stands, I completely agree with the close decision.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your description here does not reflect the actual question you've asked. There is a problem statement and some github link. That's it. That does not demonstrate research. It simply reads like "I want to do X". And that is not really a question.

Comment: Note -Arslan also [initiated a chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/603) regarding this, where we talked about how the question could be made to be a better fit. Feel free to read the transcript or join in. He's got a rather interesting idea.

Comment: @user414076: I did put my efforts and explored the windows Phone accelerometer and got its x,y and z values. And I found that normally people did in Android earlier and they developed their algorithm and noise detection and threshold settings. So I just want to know what kind algorithm they applied as surely some research behind that algorithm. So In this case, If I am not familiar with Android and cannot understand that code, then I start working on research again and try to invent again but not to ask someone help as he did something already

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem with the type of question you seem to be referencing is that they amount to asking for a tutorial for how to do something. Such questions don't tend to end up very well here; they either end up soliciting just lists of links (check out here, or there, or that other place), mostly meaningless posting of buzzwords (use frobbles to reticulate your splines!), or actual, full-length tutorials.

Such answers tend to make things a bit 'messy' around here, and tend not to be so useful without considerable, additional discussion (How do I use a frobble for reticulation? I thought they were only used for tweezing?) They can also invite lot of opinions (you don't need to reticulate your splines! They come reticulated already if you use the widget library!)

The end result isn't as directly useful as the content we prefer around here, as it often leads to as many additional questions as answers. Additionally, the heavy content that they can invite tends to make for a bit of noise for the sake of searches. (Lots of people talking about reticulating splines, resulting in people coming here when searching for information on how to play SimCity!)

This is one reason we generally like a question to try to show some specific code examples; that tends to focus the answers on something that can be nice and short - and to the point.

So basically, looking for a 'starting point' doesn't tend to really work out well. It sounds like you have some ideas where to start there. I would recommend you dig deeper, or also consider the possibility that you might try in the related chat rooms on Stack Overflow sometime, to see if someone has any useful links or information to which they can point you.

Also, look closely to see if perhaps you do have enough to formulate a question that does have more information. You have seen some examples in other frameworks/languages that maybe you understand a little better, or at least could serve as a starting point? Try to formulate some well-educated 'pseudo code' in your target language. *That might actually be a helpful thing to do, all by itself.* Or, it might help you formulate a better question.

One thing to watch for that could be related here is not to try to post a "I've found this example in language X, could you translate it into language Y?"... but if you do have *that* question in mind, you could use the 'pseudo code' idea above to help; Make an earnest attempt, and fill out what you don't quite have with something as close as you think you can get...

I'm starting to wander and ramble a bit here, but I just wanted to toss out some possible ideas to help. Asking a good question is *not easy to do*, absolutely. But the rewards are... rewarding!

Comment: I agreed on point that question should be concluded in ending point and in some positive way. And I want to add one more thing, the question like asked above that was first time on Windows phone and never asked before, If someone will answer that question it will be great asset and will be showing some path to other users like me to get some direction. And as I believe let say you are good in Java and I never worked on java but I know .NET stuff and by chance I need to to do such thing that is already developed by other or you, I could seek your seek your help.

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz I think you have all of the elements that need to be included for the question to be good. Just add your testing, the code you used, what you discovered, why it led you to think you could get the result you're after - once you've done that then "Can I do this? If so, how?" becomes an answerable question.

Comment: @TimPost: OK Let me do that on my original question. Might be that can make sense for all.